# How to print a list of items in a multiline string output in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a list in ansible and want to print the contents in a block, if I do loop like below:

```
- test_list
    - one
    - two
    - three
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ test_list }}"
```

it will produce output something like:

```
{ msg: "one" }
{ msg: "two" }
{ msg: "three" }
```

here I have multiple `msg` values, I want output like:

```
msg:"one
two
three"
```

where list items are broken won into multiple lines. Can anyone direct me to the correct path or provide a hint.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by the following steps :

1. Set `callback plugin` to `debug` using the following command:

`export ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=debug`

2. Replace `loop` with `for loop` on `jinja2`:

Example:

The desired output could be obtained using the following playbook:

```
---

- name: Sample playbook
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    test_list:
    - one
    - two
    - three

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{% for item in test_list %}{{ item + '\n'}}{% endfor %}"
```

The above playbook would  result in:

```
PLAY [Sample playbook] ***************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {}

MSG:

one
two
three

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

if you need starting/ending double quotes:

```
msg: "\"{% for item in test_list %}{{ item + '\n'}}{% endfor %}\""
```